# Why does transfer of a TAR file slow down so significantly mid-transfer?

Tags: rsync, tar, scp, file-transfer

I'm trying to transfer a 30GB TAR file between two servers. My problem is transfer starts at a fast rate of roughly 10s MB/s, but after 11% of the file transfer the speed slows enormously to 100s KB/s.

This behaviour is identical across scp and rsync.

Some things I've thought of but discarded

- The believe the issue can't be lots of small files because it's a single TAR file that's being transferred
- Read/write speeds on each machine are clearly sufficient as they are fast during the start of the transfer, and no other significant processes are running on the machines
- The machine that's being written to has plenty of disk remaining

Command I'm using is:

```
rsync -avh --progress file.tar.gz  user@XX.XX.XX.XX:/filepath
```

Edit: I rent both machines. They're both VPS VMs running Ubuntu 20.04.

What do you think could be the cause?

Comment: we'll need more information on these servers. Are you talking to a container, or to a VM, or to a bare metal server? Do you own or rent or cloud-occupy any of this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! They're both VPS VMs running Ubuntu 20.04. I rent both.

Comment: Are you using direct rsync or are you using ssh?

Comment: @Shadur `rsync` will use `ssh` for network transfer by default.

Comment: Yep it’s using ssh

Comment: Still don't know what the problem with rsync and scp is but I don't run into the same issue when sending the file via a http server, so I guess the problem must be with ssh.

Unresolved but I have a workaround.